# Profit and Loss question......

Tags: arithmetic

A fruitseller by means of a false balance cheats $20$% in buying and also cheats the buyer to the same extent in selling. Find the gain percent on his outlay.

My Approach:

He cheats $20$% on purchasing means;
He pays only Rs. $100$ which worth Rs. $120$.

Again, he cheats $20$% on selling means;
He sells the fruits worthing Rs. $100$ for Rs. $120$.

Now, what should I do? Please help me to continue.

Comment: If the true value of the fruit-sellers purchase is Rs $120$ and he cheats $20\%$, then he pays Rs $20$ - Rs $120*0.2$ = $120 - 24$ = Rs $96$, not Rs $100$.

Comment: How is that? Please clarify a bit more.

Comment: What is 20% of 120? It isn't 20, its 24